# Help why to apply PCA here

Tags: unsupervised-learning, pca

Lets say we have a dataset of 9 dimensional points and I want to apply k-means algorithm.
I was studying an example where they apply PCA before fitting the data into the clustering algorithm. The problem is that I cannot understand why PCA is used in this unsupervised learning setting.

In case we were in a supervised learning setting and we had a labeled dataset I understand that high feauture correlations might lead to bad performance of the resulting predictor. But in this unsupervised learning setting it is not clear to me what's the use of applying PCA. Could you please assist in this ?

Comment: The intuition is the same as in supervised learning. By applying PCA you transform the initial data to a space with fewer dimensions where the linear relationship between the new dimensions is zero. Thereby you will be applying k-means to this new space, hopefully getting better results.

Comment: What does better "results" means ? I do not have any labels to compare.. In other words, how can I compare the a cluster prior to applying PCA and a cluster after applying PCA ?

Comment: This answer from CV on evaluation metrics for unsupervised methods may help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79028/performance-metrics-to-evaluate-unsupervised-learning/79079#79079

Comment: It's mostly about evaluating why you are using kmeans and what you expect of it, then if your results (the motivation behind using kmeans) get better after applying PCA, that's a good thing

Comment: yes that is quite helpful.. thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that :)